# Raphaeljs path id inside a set attributes

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm working on a map with Raphaeljs and I have the paths inside a set because I want all of them to have the same attributes and all is good but now I would like to set an id to each path and I did it to one but the attributes got lost, so my question is...Is there a way to have an path.id inside a set with the set attributes? Thanks

Here is the file http://jsfiddle.net/tLSpv/2/

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,540, 615);

var newmexico = paper.set();

newmexico.push(
paper.path("M343.249,11.503l-1.658,3.554l-0.474,16.822c0,0-3.554-0.711-5.449-0.711 s-5.686,3.554-5.449,4.265c0.237,0.711-1.895,13.268-1.895,14.215s3.554,4.502,3.317,5.449c-0.237,0.948-0.711,3.554-0.474,4.502 c0.237,0.948,0.711,7.345,0.474,9.477c-0.237,2.132,0.948,11.846-1.658,13.268h42.883v5.449h38.855h37.197V73.103l1.303-1.303V1.239 L340.643,1.18v4.4L343.249,11.503z").node.id = 'colfax';
).attr({    
            fill: '#F7F0EA',
            stroke: '#006599',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            cursor: 'pointer' 
 })

.hover(function () {
 this.animate({fill: '#006599'}, 300);
    },
    function () {
    this.animate({fill: '#F7F0EA'}, 300)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. Add `Raphaels data()` function to your on top of your attribute list.

Exp:

```
for (var i = 0, i < 5, i++) {
    paper.circle(10 + 15 * i, 10, 10)
         .attr({fill: "#000"})
         .data("i", i)
         .click(function () {
            alert(this.data("i"));
         });
}
```

This little example is taken from **[here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data)**. `data` Adds or retrieves given value associated with given key. In this case `"i"` is a key and `i` is the value.

This is how I assign ids to my Raphael objects. Good Luck

Comment: I was able to do it using the explicit method used here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112830/same-hover-function-for-multiple-paths-in-raphael. Thanks.